# FileUpload in .NET not saving image

Tags: .net, asp.net, file-upload

Here's my code

```
Dim amPhotoPath As String = "\graphics\Profiles\" & ViewState("fileName")
personalPhotoUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~") & amPhotoPath)
```

For some reason the image is not saving.. if I debug the code, and get the URL in Quickwatch, the folder opens, so the path is correct, but it just doesnt save! I have just set up the permissions because I thought it was because of that, but to no avail! I have no idea whats going wrong here, I am missing something?

Thanks guys

Comment: The viewstate is just the image name...

Comment: Do you get any exception or the image is not saved at all? When you debug what's the value of ViewState("fileName")?

Comment: the viewstate has the actual image name, it is not null or something which will give problems. 

and it gives no errors at all... it just doesnt save :s

Comment: Is the FileUpdload control's InputStream non-null? I.e. Does it have a valid file?

Comment: Do you get an exception?  If not, then we need a lot more code to look at.

Comment: This is the table row, which the file upload is in ( its set to visible = true on page load )

 <tr id="PersonalPhoto" runat="server" visible="false">
                                            <td class="TabularC" id="Td14" width="170" runat="server" align="left">
                                                Personal Photo</td>
                                            <td class="TabularC">
                                                <asp:FileUpload ID="personalPhotoUpload" CssClass="button" runat="server" /></td>
                                        </tr>

Comment: nope, the abhout the OS, its XP

Comment: Could this be that because I have a series of button clicks after choosing the photo, that the path gets erased?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.hasfile.aspx). You need to use the FileUpload controls properties to check if  the FileUpload control has a file, and then use the PostedFile property to get your file name.

Comment: +1 Good idea, follow a standard example first then customize if you are unsure how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim amPhotoPath As String = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/graphics/Profiles"), ViewState("filename"))
personalPhotoUpload.SaveAs(amPhotoPath)
```

I'm not sure what you had in your view state, but at least this why it'll be easier to verify your path while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verified that the personalPhotoUpload.ContentLength() > 0 ?

If it isn't, then that is your problem. If your filebytes is zero then there isn't an uploaded file.

Extracted from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filebytes.aspx) documentation page:

> The  FileUpload  control does not
>   automatically read the file from the
>   client. You must explicitly provide a
>   control or mechanism to allow the user
>   to submit the specified file. For
>   example, you can provide a button that
>   the user can click to upload the file.
>   The code that you write to save the
>   specified file could call the
>   FileBytes property, which returns the
>   contents of the file.
>
> Before calling the FileBytes property,
>   you should use the HasFile property to
>   verify that the FileUpload control
>   contains a file to upload. If the
>   HasFile returns true, call the
>   FileBytes property. If it returns
>   false, display a message to the user
>   indicating that the control does not
>   contain a file. If you do not provide
>   error-handling code to verify that a
>   file exists, an attempt to save a
>   nonexistent file throws an
>   HttpException exception.

Comment: The filebytes of the fileupload, is 0... what does that mean?